# PHP: save a file (generated by aspx) to server

Tags: php, asp.net, xml, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

I have an url provided by a wholesaler. Url generates xml file which I need to save on my server.
I use PHP - file_get_contents and file_put_contents to do that:

```
$savepath = "path_to_my_server_folder";
$xmlurl = "http://usistema.eurodigital.lt/newxml/xmlfile.aspx?xml=labas&code=052048048048051057049050048049052";
file_put_contents($savepath.'eurodigital.xml', file_get_contents($xmlurl));
```

File is generated on my server, but its content is empty. I have no problems with other xml files if I provide direct xml url, but in this situation file is generated by aspx file dynamically. Xml url is  actual url I use. When I open xmlurl in browser, xml file gets saved to device.

Can you help me with moving xml to my server? What function should I use? Is it even possible to do that using PHP 5? "allow_url_fopen" is ON.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I tried visiting that URL and nothing showed up. Are you sure you're actually getting any XML to save?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, tried it again a minute ago It takes some time (about 10-20 sec) file to be generated, then new_file.xml is automatically saved.

Comment: I've tried your code (PHP 7.3) and it works well. Add these line before the script and if you'll get some errors, please update your question.
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);`
Btw, I assume the problem may be PHP memory because the XML file you download is too long.

Comment: OK, I'll try. Its probably not memory issue, as I successfully saved xml when I used direct link. Can this be a PHP version issue?

Comment: @aywars Please place the error reporting to the file. Then we will know more.

Comment: Its: failed to open stream: Connection timed out in...